# Kafka 2.9.2-0.8.1.1 no KeyedMessage parameter for producer.send

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I am trying to send a message to Kafka in java. My project is using kafka_2.9.2-0.8.1.1.jar via the maven dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
  <artifactId>kafka_2.9.2</artifactId>
  <version>0.8.1.1</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.apache.zookeeper</groupId>
      <artifactId>zookeeper</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

The problem I am having is with my producer. I want to send a KeyedMessage and via the documentation here: http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#producerapi it states that the producer.send method should take a KeyedMessage for its parameter. When I inspect the options avaiable for the producer.send call, it only allows a ProducerData object as an acceptable paramater.

My code is set up like so:

```java
    private String topic;   
    private String key;
    private Properties props = new Properties();
    private Producer<String,String> producer;

    props.put("serializer.class", "kafka.serializer.StringEncoder");
    props.put("zk.connect", "127.0.0.1:2181");  

    //create the producer
    producer = new Producer<String, String>(new ProducerConfig(props));   

    String topic = "test";
    String key = "test_key";
    String message = "test_msg";

    KeyedMessage<String, String> data = new KeyedMessage<String, String>(topic, key, message);
    producer.send(data)  <---- ERROR is here, send method not allowed param of KeyedMessage
```

The actual error is this states as this:

```
 The method send(ProducerData<String,String>) in the type Producer<String,String> is not applicable for the arguments (KeyedMessage<String,String>)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to define

```
 props.put("partitioner.class", "example.producer.SimplePartitioner");
```

The [wiki](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/0.8.0+Producer+Example) page says

> The third property  "partitioner.class" defines what class to use to determine which Partition in the Topic the message is to be sent to. This is optional, but for any non-trivial implementation you are going to want to implement a partitioning scheme. More about the implementation of this class later. If you include a value for the key but haven't defined a partitioner.class Kafka will use the default partitioner. If the key is null, then the Producer will assign the message to a random Partition.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't add the "partitioner.class" property the producer will follow round-robin assignment between the partitions of that particular topic.

```
 props.put("partitioner.class", "example.producer.SimplePartitioner");
```

If you don't specifically need the key based partition selection omit "partitioner.class" property and define the KeyedMessage as follows,

```java
    private String topic;   
    private String key;
    private Properties props = new Properties();
    private Producer<String,String> producer;

    props.put("metadata.broker.list", "localhost:9092");
    props.put("producers.type", "sync");
    props.put("serializer.class", "kafka.serializer.StringEncoder");
    props.put("request_final.required.acks", "1");

    //create the producer
    producer = new Producer<String, String>(new ProducerConfig(props));   

    topic = "test";
    message = "test_msg";

    KeyedMessage<String, String> data = new KeyedMessage<String, String>(topic, message);
    producer.send(data)
```

Answer (score -1):

Use

```
import kafka.javaapi.producer.Producer;
```

You might have used

```
import kafka.producer.Producer;
```

Comment: Please properly introduce the code in your texts by using backticks before & after the code so that everyone can recognize the code..!